# Android Email Uri

Tags: android, email

what is the Android Email content uri.
form the Email Client source code i get the following Uri

```
content://com.android.email.provider/body
content://com.android.email.provider/message
content://com.android.email.provider/syncedMessage
content://com.android.email.provider/deletedMessage
content://com.android.email.provider/updatedMessage
content://com.android.email.provider/account
content://com.android.email.provider/accountIdAddToField
content://com.android.email.provider/attachment
content://com.android.email.provider/attachment/message
content://com.android.email.provider/mailbox
content://com.android.email.provider/mailboxIdAddToField
content://com.android.email.provider/hostauth
```

but not returning cursor when i run the following code.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.email.provider/account");
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,null,null);
```

anyone no how i can access email contents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> anyone know how i can access email
>   contents?

The Email program is not part of the SDK. It can be replaced on Android devices. The content providers can change in future versions of Android. The user might not be using that email program in the first place, using Gmail, K-9, or another third party application.

There is a useful discussion of all the reasons preventing email from being accessed via the OS: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/137111

Comment: dear you are right. And there is also no proper implementation define in the Email Client Content provider. Download the source code from the following link 
http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=summary

and check out the EmailProvider class present in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

mail is not the part of sdk so it can not be accessed directly so it should be rooted first and then your apk shuold be installed in system/app folder. after all you can fetch email information.