# Using Hashtable in Android

Tags: android, hashtable, android-spinner

How can i set the hash table?I've two variables,which are book name and number of chapter,inside spinner.I want to set text view according to book name and number of chapter.So how can i do it?

Comment: [Same question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193965/android-email-uri

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have your elements inside an Arraylist.

All you need to do is fetch the element that is selected in this spinner.

```
spinner
    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    //selectedItemView.invalidate()
    Toast.makeText(Registration_Screen.this,
    arrayList.get(position) + "",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    Toast.makeText(Registration_Screen.this,
        "Nothing Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
```

So now you have the position of the arraylist, where your item is present.

let mw know if this works.

Comment: Thank you it works but i already did this part.I guess i couldn't explain my question.Here is my problem:I have two spinners,when i select two items from spinners,it should load the corresponding java page that has been already created.